# Java Hibernate weird marshaling bug?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am having an issue with Spring Data JPA when it returns data from the database. I'm giving this one more shot on here. Below is the setup.

```
Spring V 1.5.15.RELEASE
PGV 9.5.4
```

SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dmg.gps_user_to_data_set (
    group_id int8 NOT NULL,
    data_set int4 NOT NULL,
    agency_id int8 NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (agency_id) REFERENCES funding_agency(agency_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id, data_set) REFERENCES data_set(group_id, data_set)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
```

Repo:

```
public interface GpsUserToDataSetTestRepository extends JpaRepository<GpsUserToDataSetTest, DataSetPK> {
    @Query(value = "select group_id,data_set,agency_id from gps_user_to_data_set where group_id=?1 and data_set=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<GpsUserToDataSetTest> test(Long groupId, Long dataSet);
    @Query(value = "select group_id,data_set,agency_id from gps_user_to_data_set where group_id=?1 and data_set=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> test2(Long groupId, Long dataSet);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "GPS_USER_TO_DATA_SET")
public class GpsUserToDataSetTest implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DataSetPK primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "AGENCY_ID")
    private Long agencyId;

}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println("ID: "+dataSetPK);

System.out.println("YYY : ");
gpsUserToDataSetTestRepo.test(dataSetPK.getGroupId(), dataSetPK.getDataSetId()).stream().forEach(e -> {
    try {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(e));
    } catch(JsonProcessingException jpe) {
    }
});

System.out.println("ZZZ: ");
gpsUserToDataSetTestRepo.test2(dataSetPK.getGroupId(), dataSetPK.getDataSetId()).stream().forEach(e -> {
    try {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(e));
    } catch(JsonProcessingException jpe) {
    }
});
```

So I run this and I get two different results, I would expect when the interface GpsUSerToDataSetTest the encapsulated information should be exacly the same as when I run the same query with java.lang.Object, but you can see the ids are not the same, below is the data in the DB & the stdOut dump.

I dont even know what to say here, this just seems very odd to me, and potentially a bug?

DB:

```
group_id |data_set |agency_id |
---------|---------|----------|
1356     |1        |2         |
1356     |1        |2         |
1356     |1        |19        |
```

Dump:

```
ID: DataSetPK(dataSetId=1, groupId=1356)
YYY : 
{"primaryKey":{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356},"agencyId":2}
{"primaryKey":{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356},"agencyId":2}
{"primaryKey":{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356},"agencyId":2}
ZZZ: 
[1356,1,2]
[1356,1,2]
[1356,1,19]
```

as you can see the EXACT same query returns two different results on the agencyId as soon as I add the GpsUserToDataSetTest to the result set for marshaling. Any feedback would be good, I am lost at this point.

**EDIT:**
Updated Entity:

```
public class GpsUserToDataSetTest implements Serializable {

//    @EmbeddedId
//    private DataSetPK primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "DATA_SET")
    @Id
    private Long dataSetId;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    @Id
    private Long groupId;

    @Column(name = "AGENCY_ID")
    private Long agencyId;

}
```

Edit based on Comments:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "GPS_USER_TO_DATA_SET")
public class GpsUserToDataSetTest implements Serializable {

//    @EmbeddedId
//    private DataSetPK primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "DATA_SET")
    private Long dataSetId;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Long groupId;

    @Column(name = "AGENCY_ID")
    @Id
    private Long agencyId;

}

ID: DataSetPK(dataSetId=1, groupId=1356)
YYY : 
{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356,"agencyId":2}
{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356,"agencyId":2}
{"dataSetId":1,"groupId":1356,"agencyId":19}
ZZZ: 
[1356,1,2]
[1356,1,2]
[1356,1,19]
```

Comment: Can you share `gpsUserToDataSetTestRepo.test()` and `gpsUserToDataSetTestRepo.test2()` method implemeentation. Looks like there is a difference and most likely that's the reason you are getting different results.

Comment: Yes, they're part of the original post, as you can see they are exactly the same with the exception being the return type.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the query result is captured into `List<GpsUserToDataSetTest>` in `test1()` the `GpsUserToDataSetTest ORM`  objects are populated and added to the list. Hence, the `JSON` converted string is the exact representation of the `ORM`.

On the other hand, when the query result is captured into `List<Object>` in `test2()` these are populated as mere values array and then added to the list. Hence, the `JSON` representation has only values array.

Write a new method `test3()` in the repository and capture the results into `List<Map<String, String>>` and observe the output. You'll notice plain individual key values (no field like primaryKey etc.) in the `JSON` string.

**Edit**

Also, all the rows returned from test1() is duplicate because of the primary key (@Id or @EmbeddedId) fields in the rows returned are the same. Hibernate cache is the cause here. This is not a bug in Hibernate rather the data is the database should be fixed or the @Id annotation should be used correctly.

Comment: So the issue isnt the formatting of the result, it's the data within the result. Please see agencyId in both test cases.

as you can see on is 2,2,2 (bad result) and the other is 2,2,19 (the correct result)

Comment: Most likely that is because of the same primary key values (`dataSetId` and `groupId`) in all 3 rows. Can you insert some more rows with different primary key field values and check the result?

Comment: There are millions of rows, this is a small set of data. I think maybe you are not understanding the issue. 

I run the same exact query in the DB and it is correct, when I return a java.lang.object, the data is correct, as soon as I change it to GpsUserToDataSetTest is when the rows return as one row duplicated 3 times. All the code is posted.

Comment: As for your above Edit: the data is correct, I possibly could believe it's a cache issue, which sound like a bug considering the query that is dumped from hibernate returns the correct data also. As for he composite id I was under the impression this is completely valid and used correctly. Maybe I'm missing something but I use this same exact pattern in a lot of code and this is the only process that is returning the incorrect data.

Comment: @MichaelM I understood the issue. Please see the edit section of the answer. Your primary keys are colliding in the Hibernate layer. Either fix the data in the database to remove duplicates (same `dataSetId and groupId`) or remove the `@Id/@Embedded` Id annotation and verify. I suggest for a moment remove the `@Embedded` Id annotation and verify. In that case you may need to move those fields to the ORM directly instead of placing in `DataSetPK` class.

Comment: @MichaelM If you mark a field or set of fields as primary key those can't be repeated in the same table. This is the premise of the primary key in all databases. Hibernate is exactly following that.  Maybe (not sure entirely) Hibernate is using the primary key as the key in the cache and hence the issue. On the other hand, when you are not using ORM (in `test2()`), it is not using Hibernate cache at all & hence you get all rows including duplicates. So, we can't say it is a Hibernate bug. By the way, what is the primary key in this table in the database? Is that reflected in the ORM correctly?

Comment: Ok got it, so I moved the id to the entity and still have the same result.

Comment: Can you clarify *I moved the id to the entity*? Can you edit the question to reflect this change or put in the comment?

Comment: Ok. remove @Id annotation from both the fields and check.

Comment: Java will not let me compile without telling it what the @Id is

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: org.....gps.GpsUserToDataSetTest

Comment: I see. Do you have a primary key created in the table? It does not look like. What is unique in the table? Put those fields in the @EmbeddedId class (workaround).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was burning on this all night, you saved my day, nice to know this happens.

Comment: @MichaelM the Id collision is the key point here. Good to know that it is working and clear now :)